# Cannot access "Authentication / Authorization" for my azure web app

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

Hi there when open azure web app and navigate to Authentication / Authorization tab it loads forever and i cannot see any settings and here is image
[image]

How can i get rid of this ?

Comment: There is no code, problem is in azure portal i just need to access this page @user3060520

Comment: You said you cannot see settings. Try to turn the switch on. If you dont see this feature may be it is not available in your region.

Comment: Have you configured the Easy Auth feature on the Old Portal a long time ago and opening the new Portal for the first time ?

Can you give more information ? on when this started happening and if you have a valid configuration already setup ?

Answer (score 0):

Try once restarting the app. If it doesnot works enable authentication. If it doesn't work then might be that service is not available in your azure pass